# refresh div (populated by jquery) when form (inside div) is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my scenario.    I have a 'Master Page (Course_Maintenance.php)' that has 2 divs on it.  The first is populated from the code on Course_Maintenace.php.   The second div populates using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[id='SelectCourse']").change(function() {
        var link = 'CourseTeeInfo.php?CourseID='+$(this).val();
        $('#CourseTeeInfo').load(link);
    })
});
```

The CourseTeeInfo.php page has a form that populates and works perfectly.   I use a staging system on that page:

```
        // Get stage of form 
    if(!isset($_POST['btn_submit']) || !$_POST['btn_submit']) { $stage=0; }
    if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']) && $_POST['btn_submit'] == 'submit') { $stage=1; }
```

So once the form is filled out and validated, I use javascript to change the value of btn_submit to come back to the form to use PHP to write to the MySQL database:

```
            function ValidateForm() {
            if(!noErrors2()) { alert("You must fix errors on page before submitting"); }
            document.getElementById('btn_submit').value = "submit";
            document.TeeInfo.submit();
        }
```

Currently I have Stage 2 just echoing the $_POST variable to the screen.   This all works if I call CourseTeeInfo.php directly.    However, when I click the Update button on the form (which fires the ValidateForm() javascript) within the div on Course_Maintenace - the div refreshes to a blank screen rather than the $_POST variable display (as it does running directly).

Any insight on how to have the div refresh properly in the parent (Course_Maintenace.php) window would be greatly appreciated.   I simply want the div to work exactly like the form works if called directly.    My goal is that after I successfully write the record (in $stage=1) that I will reload the form (yet again) back to $stage=0 which will then have the new/updated information.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I think what you need is an AJAX approach, that way you'll be able to call the PHP and echo the result to the div without refreshing the page or a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the approach slightly and used jQuery AJAX calls to write to the MySQL database (instead of reloading the form).   After writing the record, I simply refreshed the div using the jQuery .load function.